# SRX100 in bootloop. Flash storage problem?

Tags: juniper, troubleshooting, juniper-srx, srx

About a month ago one of my SRX100 started to go into a bootloop for no obvious reason to me.

After some hours, it eventually stopped and booted up the system again (primary) and I was happy that I could create a rescue config. However, I did not have time to copy the configuration to a remote host before this issue started again.
The device boots up, give me a few error messages that varies, such as:

```
SUMMARY INFORMATION BAD
SALVAGE? yes

BLK(S) MISSING IN BIT MAPS
SALVAGE? yes

FREE BLK COUNT(S) WRONG IN SUPERBLK
SALVAGE? yes
```

Sometimes it also says (but as stated before, it varies):

```
INCORRECT BLOCK COUNT I=33517 (16 should be 0)
CORRECT? yes
```

So I started google a bit and found several posts that looked similar and they where all recommended to install a fresh version of JUNOS from a USB or TFTP server. So I did the same. I installed the newest version I could find (junos-12.1X45-D15.5-domestic) using TFTP with the `--format` option but I am still having the same problem.

Basically, the device is fine and can boot up, I can even log in (the interfaces haven't activated yet though), and after about 50-60 sec it just reboots again, without any messages on the console. Looks like it got a power reset or something.

I've also tried running the `nand-mediack.sh` utility (just running the script, no options) but it just comes back empty.

So, anyone have a clue of what's going on here? Is there any logs I can look at? Can I transfer my config out of there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a bad "disk", but never having opened an SRX100, I don't know what's in it -- 'tho I doubt there's a spinning disk in it.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I figured as well. And you are right, there is no spinning disk in it. Heres a picture of its internals:
http://andkorn.org/images/posts/2013-05-24-juniper-srx100h-internals2.jpg

Comment: SRX100 uses FLASH chips... not disks

Comment: If you still haven't solved this, is there enough time where the device is up that you could pulls some logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config is possibly safe (if you care about them you should consider rancid or make manual backups) as it's on a different partition.

If you place the install image on a FAT32 formatted USB key you can reinstall JunOS from there, however you may need to use the reformat option which will wipe any config.

Juniper doc:
http://www.trapezenetworks.com/techpubs/en_US/junos12.2/topics/task/installation/security-junos-os-boot-loader-usb-storage-device-srx-series-device-installing.html